# Annotation Visibility between EJB and Client layer

Tags: java, annotations, ejb

I am attempting to read method annotations in my web layer that are defined on classes in my EJB3 layer.

The object I am working with is a JPA defined entity on my EJB layer that is being fetched with a local ejb lookup to my client layer. When I attempt to read the annotations on the methods they are missing. It appears that all of the annotations are being stripped off of the objects that are being passed from the EJB layer to the Client layer. 
The annotation I would like to read is not one of the EJB or JPA annotations but something to drive the processing of the class on the web tier.

If this is typical behavior of the servers then I can write the process differently, annotating the class was the simplest solution.

Thanks

-Scott

Comment: Passing a JPA entity via EJB to the client tier? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: JPA objects are just classes with annotations. The classes that I am passing represent the data that the web client needs to use. The classes in this case are not populated by JPA, they just happen to also have those annotations.

Comment: Generally, in an n-tier application, you wouldn't want to couple your presentation and data tiers, that is why I asked the question.

Comment: Understood, I still need to be able to pass the data between the different layers of my application and it has not made sense to develop another layer of data objects outside those that already define the data I am using. The question here though is the broader question of the life of the annotations that exist on the objects.  I can understand stripping off EJB and JPA annotations, but I have not seen any references to them all being stripped.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the ease of EJB 3 tripped me up here.

In the client of an EJB app I am not looking at an instance of the Class from the EJB tier but a generated instance based on a generated interface from the EJB layer. Therefore the annotations defined on the EJB layer class are not present in the client layer of the application.